# Snapshot/volume removal from EC2

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have scripts that create many snapshots of my EBS backed Windows instance. You can somewhat consider that I am building a tree of images, where I branch out and create snapshots at various times of the days. An example:

```
> Source Windows AMI -> Snapshot 1
>                             -> Snapshot 1.1
>                                         -> Snapshot 1.1.1
>                             -> Snapshot 1.2
>                    -> Snapshot 2
>                             -> Snapshot 2.1
>                             -> Snapshot 2.2
>                             ....
```

I now want to clean up my workspace. My understand is that snapshots are differential. So in the example above, the item 'Snapshot 1' would be a complete image, whereas 'Snapshot 1.1' would be a much smaller file containing only the binary diff. Is my understanding of this correct? If so, then what happens when I delete 'Snapshot 1.1' --- does it Amazon forbid me from doing this because 'Snapshot 1.1.1' is a dependency, or does it allow this and things simply break in the future?

Comment: Beginner - This feels like it might be a better question for [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/questions)

Answer (score 1):

Snapshots are not really stored as a tree hierarchy, as per your depiction. Instead, there is just a bucket of 'blocks' and the snapshot identifier is a pointer to which blocks are required to rebuild your image from the base image. Take more snapshots, and you will just be generating more 'diff' blocks and new snapshot identifiers that point to these blocks.

I may be mistaken with this assertion, but you won't save any disk space (+ money) if you delete the intermediate snapshots (ie. v2.0 in your example) from your EC2 profile. This is because the v2.0 blocks will still be required to build v2.1, v2.2... So if you want to remove snapshots to save money then you really need to delete those those that exist as the leafs of your conceptual tree of snapshots.

BTW, the exact representation of a tree of snapshots is how they are represented at this EC2 management tool: http://LabSlice.com. It may be worth a look if you are building snapshots for lab type purposes. (Disclaimer: I work there).

Answer (score 0):

> 'Snapshot 1.1' would be a much smaller file containing only the binary diff. Is my understanding of this correct?

Yes

> 'If so, then what happens when I delete 'Snapshot 1.1' --- does it Amazon forbid me from doing this because 'Snapshot 1.1.1' is a dependency, or does it allow this and things simply break in the future?

Good question, but you need to give amazon a little more credit :)
If you delete snapshot 1.1, then only the blocks that are not referenced by any other snapshot are deleted and this means that Snapshot 1.1.1 will work just fine.

A nice explanation (along with neat diagrams) of this can be found [here](http://blog.rightscale.com/2008/08/20/amazon-ebs-explained/)